# Laravel 5.3 :manual pagination with custom array not displaying links in page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel-5.3

I am trying to implement a manual pagination with custom array in Laravel everything works fine except with the pagination links.
Pagination links not displayed in the page

**Controller**

```
                 $perPage = 3;
                 $currentPage = Input::get('page',1)-1;
                 $pagedData = array_slice($this->data->arts->toArray(),$currentPage*$perPage,$perPage);
                 $this->data['paged'] = new Paginator($pagedData, count($this->data->arts), $perPage);
```

**View.blade**

```
@forelse($data['paged']->chunk(3) as $array)
   ......
   @endforelse
   <!--displaying links-->
   {{$data['paged']->links()}}
```

`$data['paged']->links()` give an empty bootstrap pagination markup

**Update**

ouput of `dd($data['paged'])`

```
Paginator {#233 ▼
  #hasMore: false
  #items: Collection {#235 ▶}
  #perPage: 7
  #currentPage: 3
  #path: "/"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `dd($data['paged'])` in your question?